# TypeError: this.getResults(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a javascript class and I am using `this.loadResults('cpu').bind(this)` to load a specific result, which can differentiate based on the string - such as `cpu` or `other` - input.

Find below a minimum viable example:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

//class Builder {
constructor() {
  this.events();
}

events() {
  $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this));
}

// methods
ourClickDispatcher(e) {
  var currentButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm");

  if (currentButton.data('exists') == 'cpu') {
    this.loadResults('cpu').bind(this)
  }

  if (currentButton.data('exists') == 'other') {
    this.loadResults('other').bind(this)
  }
}

loadResults(part) {
  console.log(`loadResults ${part} clicked`)
  //result logic ...
}
//}

//export default Builder;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-exists="cpu" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                            CPU
                                        </button>
```

When I am running the script in firefox I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: this.loadResults(...) is undefined[Learn More]  scripts-bundled.js:26481:9
    ourClickDispatcher https://link.com/js/scripts-bundled.js:26481:9
    bound ourClickDispatcher self-hosted:915:17
    jQuery.event.dispatch https://link.com/js/scripts-bundled.js:5274:16
    jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle
```

Any suggestions why I get this error?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: where did you create an object from your `Builder` class?

Comment: @mrquad A TypeError is thrown when an operand or argument passed to a function is incompatible with the type expected by that operator or function.
ie, these show up when a value is not the expected type

Comment: @ManuAVS Thx for your reply! However, I cannot see that I am passing the wrong type as I am expecting a string in the function. Any suggestions from your site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure yet, but to confirm, when you're binding 'this' to this.loadResults('cpu'), I am assuming loadResults should be returning a function. Is it perhaps returning undefined since you don't intend for it to return something?

Can I ask why you are binding 'this' to the return value of loadResults? Maybe you don't need the bind there at all since you're calling loadResults method style. loadResults will have access to 'this' even without binding 'this'

It doesn't make sense to me to write

```
this.loadResults('other').bind(this)
```

unless you expect this.loadResults('other') to return a function, and you are binding 'this' to that function. But I don't think you are doing that since you don't do anything with it afterwards.

My guess is to just get rid of the .bind(this)